# How to stay in zoom in tmux if select-pane command issued?

Tags: vim, tmux

I'll explain what I mean. Suppose I've created a horizontal split and then zoomed the top pane.

Then when I'm pressing `C-w-l` bounded to `select-pane -R` (I'm using vim and TmuxNavigator plugin to 'seamless' navigation between tmux and vim panes) tmux would unzoom pane and the active pane would remain the same. I don't like that.

If I would press `C-w-j` bounded to `select-pane -D` tmux would unzoom and make bottom pane active which I like very much.

How can I disable the first behaviour while saving the second?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to replace your bindings on the binds you want to have the zoom after pressing. You would need to add the `resize-pane -Z` command directly after the normal behavior of the key. For example if `C-<prefix>-l` is normally bound to `select-pane -L` you would change it to `select-pane -L ; resize-pane -Z`. You can do this with the following command.

```
:bind-key -T prefix l select-pane -L\; resize-pane -Z
```

**Note**: You need to escape the `;` otherwise tux will interpret `resize-pane -Z` as its own command after `bind-key`

Comment: Okay, so first of all adding `resize-pane -Z` after `select-pane -L` messes tmux somehow and it start to showing something like random letters instead of terminal. But even if this would work properly, I don't think that this is the answer to my question. Imagine I would have two windows in vertical split and then zommed into the left one, then pressed `C-w-l`. Tmux would unzoom right pane and bring me to the left one and then it would zoom into left one, which isn't what I want.

Comment: @user1685095 did you give it a try? It all happens so fast you can't visually tell.

Comment: I told you I did. Tmux screwed the terminal completely after that. It's not about speed it's about wrong logic. If there is a pane in the left I want to switch to it. If there isn't I want to stay in zoom. And what your solution would do AFAIK is it would switch me to the left pane and zoom into it. What I need is a way to determine if there is a window next to the current.